Line 1122: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
This is DSA Question. I'm getting at error at runtime

error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

I'm getting this error in leetcode while submitting, but it is working fine in my local system.
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define ll long long
    #define nl '\n'
    #define py cout << "YES" << endl
    #define pn cout << "NO" << endl
    
    int main(){
        
        vector<int> nums = {0,2,3,4,6,8,9};
        int n = nums.size();
    
        string str = to_string(nums[0]);
        
        vector<string> ans; 
    
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            char lastChar = str[str.length()-1];
            int no = lastChar - '0';
    
         
            if(nums[i] == no+1){
                if(str.length() > 1){
                    str[str.length() - 1] = '0' + nums[i];
                }else{
                    str += "->" + to_string(nums[i]);
                }
            }else{
                ans.push_back(str);
                str = to_string(nums[i]);
            }
        }
    
        ans.push_back(str);
        
    
        for (auto &&i : ans)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
        
        return 0;
    }


Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?
(3) #define ll long long

Whatever resource you're using to learn C++, drop it like a hot potato! It makes you a much worse programmer than you should be.

Read the description of the [tag:dsa] tag one more time.

Inappropriate DSA tag removed.

I cannot see any errors in your code, and it also runs fine for me. I would double check that the code you have submitted to leetcode is the same as the code you have posted here. If you're still having problems I suggest you post to leetcode's furum because I don't think that the problem is in this code (but I could be wrong).

Of course if nums was an empty vector, or if it contained negative numbers then you would have a problem. Are you sure that is not the case when running on leetcode? Do you know for sure that the case you present above is that same as the case that errors on leetcode?

I have absolutely no idea what I am looking at in all honesty but the issue is most likely in the sample set that leetcode is using to run the program, it could potentially be throwing in an empty vector as nums, so any time you try to access an index it will be a null ptr deref, make sure to check that nums is actually populated.

Note that str[str.length() - 1] can be simplified to str.back()

By the way, there are easier ways to get or set the last digit of an integer number, than converting it to or from a string.

Those macros (#define) are just obfuscating your code - don't do that.

for(int i=1; i<n; i++) looks very suspicious. Indexing in C++ starts at 0, not at 1.

When you asked this question on the LeetCode forums, what answers did you get from there?  Could you please provide a link here to the discussion happening over there?  Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
